# What is: Bad_dump!missing_teb (Windows Phone Dev Center Crash Log)

Tags: crash, windows-phone-8.1, out-of-memory, crash-reports, crash-dumps

The following 2 crashes are being reported as our WP 8.1 app's highest occurance crashes based on Window's developer center's crash logs.

Any clue what they mean or how to debug them?  I suspect 'out of memory' but would like to confirm.

First:

> bad_dump!missing_teb   BAD_DUMP_MISSING_MEMORY_MISSING_CLR_METADATA_bad_dump!missing_teb

Second:

> bad_dump!missing_teb   BAD_DUMP_MISSING_MEMORY_NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_ZEROED_STACK_MISSING_CLR_METADATA_bad_dump!missing_teb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been told by a Microsoft Technical rep that it is a bad dump and you can not retrieve any additional information on it.

He pointed me to the following:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d74cc413-3c4b-4a92-9c42-058bc41f503f/wp81-cant-identify-the-reason-for-crash-baddumpmissingteb?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: I'm getting a fair amount of these in my app. Could it be an OutOfMemory exception?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Out of Memory.  The app I was working on was a video recording app so it would be very memory intensive and likely to have these issues. But we put in catches for those sorts of exceptions.  Almost seems like if it is an out of memory that it may not be happening in managed code.  But I can't say for certain.

Comment: I'm working on a sound/photo recording app where the problem is occurring - could be an underlying issue caused by the camera?

Comment: Same here - an app using cameras for streaming generates quite some crashes of this type.  Maybe the only way to fix this is begging Microsoft to fix the camera drivers.  We have tried our best to give the most tender and loving care of the cameras while using them.